# SFMC Cloudpages, Content Builder retrieve and creation using API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, rest, marketingcloudapi

With Chrome enforcing the blocking of mixed content and our clients looking into purchasing SAP and or SSL certs depending on their current configuration, Support have advised that cloudpages need to be re-created and are unable to assist with this process.

I can successfully create a page using the asset route (/asset/v1/content/assets) but this does not appear to create the page in a collections folder, even if using the payload from an existing page. Looking at Fiddler and the routes used by the UI it looks like they are going via an internal api we don't have access to.

Is this possible? I know there are a few undocumented rest endpoints out there, is there a cloudpage endpoint any one knows about?

Comment: You cannot create or do any API interaction with Cloudpages or Microsites. What you are referencing is an asset, which is the content but is not any of the wrapper to actually have it be a Cloudpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no longer the case that you have to create a new page to change the domain, since the October release:

[Update the Private Domain of Published Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_october_2020_cp_update_private_domain.htm&type=5)

> You can now change the private domain associated to previously published pages in the new CloudPages Preview.

> Where:The URL field is on the page properties of a landing page.

> Why: Previously, to change the domain, customers had to either contact Salesforce for rebranding or copy content from one page to another. This update allows customers to change private domain in CloudPages.

> How: Click the gear on a landing page to access the page properties, then use the URL dropdown to select the new private domain to associate with the page.